# js/array : compare 3 arrays and "transfert" one value

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I currently have three js arrays like these :

```
let array1 = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
let array2 = ['D', 'E', 'F'];
let array3 = ['G', 'H', 'I'];
```

After some users actions that remove values from arrays to add them to other arrays, what is the best way (and the logic) to make this and get an output like this :

```
array1 = ['B'];
array2 = ['D', 'E', 'F', 'A', 'I'];
array3 = ['G', 'H', 'C'];
```

Some precisions, at start the array could be empty :

```
let array1 = [];
let array2 = [];
```

then, an event is added as value :

```
array1 = ['A'];
array2 = [];
```

then, another event is added as value :

```
array1 = ['A', 'B'];
array2 = [];
```

then, same event is modified :

```
array1 = ['A'];
array2 = ['B'];
```

then, another event is added as value :

```
array1 = ['A', 'C'];
array2 = ['B'];
```

...

at the end the output could be like (with a third array) :

```
array1 = ['C'];
array2 = ['B', 'D'];
array3 = ['E', 'A'];
```

Comment: If you want `array1` to be `['CD']` then what you have `array1 = ['CD'];` works pretty well. If there is supposed to be some logic that does this automatically, maybe you should explain that.

Comment: I added some details to my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** Made it fit to your last comment and used the same examples as you there.

```js
let type1 = [];
let type2 = [];
let type3 = [];

function addOrEditChoice(user, array) {
  // remove current user from all the other arrays
  removeAlterEgos(user);

  // ...and add him to the new one:
  if (array === "type1") {
    type1.push(user);

  } else if (array === "type2") {
    type2.push(user);

  } else if (array === "type3") {
    type3.push(user);
    
  } else {
    // (just a typo fallback)
    console.log("Give a valid array-name!");
  }
}

function removeAlterEgos(user) {
  // type1.forEach((key, index) => {
  //   if (key === user) {
  //     type1.splice(index, 1);
  //   }
  // });

  // ...same but shorter:
  type1 = type1.filter(key => {
    return key !== user;
  });

  // ...and even shorter:
  type2 = type2.filter(key => key !== user);
  type3 = type3.filter(key => key !== user);
}

function printArrays() {
  console.log("array1: ", type1);
  console.log("array2: ", type2);
  console.log("array3: ", type3);
  console.log("");
}



// STEP 1
console.log("> User1 add his choice with type1:");
addOrEditChoice("user1", "type1");
printArrays();

// STEP 2
console.log("> User2 add his choice with type2:");
addOrEditChoice("user2", "type2");
printArrays();

// STEP 2
console.log("> User1 modify his choice with type2:");
addOrEditChoice("user1", "type2");
printArrays();

// STEP 2
console.log("> User3 add his choice with type1:");
addOrEditChoice("user3", "type1");
printArrays();

// STEP 2
console.log("> User3 modify his choice with type2:");
addOrEditChoice("user3", "type2");
printArrays();
```

Comment: I added some details to my question. Thank you I didn't know this `array2 = [...array2, array1[0], array3[2]]`

Comment: It's a [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: ...So to be sure I understand you right: You want to be able to add values to an array and you want to be able to modify any value in an array, but each time you edit a value, it gets moved into a new array?

Comment: Almost. I have 3 arrays which represents 3 types of choices. User1 add his choice with type1 : `array1 = ['user1'];` / User2 add his choice with type2 : `array2 = ['user2'];` / User1 modify his choice with type2 : `array1 = []; array2 = ['user2','user1'];` / User3 add his choice with type1 : `array1 = ['user3'];` like this... / User3 modify his choice with type2 : `array1 = []; array2 = ['user2','user1','user3'];` like this... but with 3 arrays and the "best" method